# Check percentage of between two big decimal values using Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Im having two Big decimal values 1. Salary 2. EMI, I'm trying to calculate the percentage of EMI in the salary. Please find the code .

```
public static final BigDecimal ONE_HUNDRED = new BigDecimal(100);   

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    BigDecimal salary = new BigDecimal("10000");
    BigDecimal emi = new BigDecimal("7000");
    System.out.println(salary.multiply(emi).divide(ONE_HUNDRED));
}
```

Output should be 70, because 7000 is 70% of 10000.

Is there any problem in the above?

P.S : Im getting those two values as Bigdecimal only from External web service. Please dont ask to use Float or Integers.

Comment: Do you think there might be a problem? Why?

Comment: Because it returns me 700000

Comment: See, that's a pretty important detail to mention in the question.

Comment: Yes, because `10000 * 7000 / 100 = 700000`.

Comment: So is the reason you want 70 because 7000 is 70% of 10000?

Comment: @RayToal, yes. You are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close!

The last line should be:

```
System.out.println(emi.multiply(ONE_HUNDRED).divide(salary));
```

This will give you

```
7000 * 100 / 10000 = 70
```